# pass the list values from Flask to JS: TypeError--: Object of type 'Undefined' is not JSON serializable cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, json, flask, undefined

I am trying to send a list generated in Flask to Javascript.
But I kept having this same issue. TypeError: Object of type 'Undefined' is not JSON serializable

Please help me.

My flask code is:

```
jsonString = json.dumps(LstSNV.serialize())
return render_template("spatial.html", AO_sDocument=occu, snvLst=jsonString)
```

My js in html page is:

```
let dataset = {{snvLst|tojson|safe}};
```

I even try to get the list directly from the html but failed.

```
            function myFunction() {
                var oldValue = document.getElementById('submit').value;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(oldValue));
                document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "LOADING...";
            }
```

I think this problem is my list is undefined but i dont know how to convert it.
Thank you.